# Required error messages not getting displayed in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with displaying required error messages in one of my pages.

HTML :

```
<div ng-form="editReservationForm">
    <form id="edit-profile" novalidate name="editReservationForm" autocomplete="off" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.employee.firstName">First Name<sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="span4" name="reservation.employee.firstName" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="reservation.employee.firstName" disabled />
                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> <!-- /control-group -->


            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.employee.lastName">Last Name<sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input class="span4" name="reservation.employee.lastName" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="reservation.employee.lastName" disabled />
                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> 

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.reservedFrom">Reserved From<sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="startDate" core-date-picker ng-model="reservation.reservedFrom" required>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>

                    <span style="color:red">{{errMessageFrom}}</span>

                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> <!-- /control-group -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.reservedTill">Reserved Till<sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
                    <!--<input type="text" style="width:150px" class="span4" name="reservedTill" placeholder="Reserved Till" data-ng-model="reservation.reservedTill"
                           validator="required" required-error-message="Date is required" valid-method="watch" id="endDate" ng-change='checkErr()' />-->
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="EndDate" core-date-picker ng-model="reservation.reservedTill"  ng-change='checkErr()' id="endDate1" required>
                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </div>
                    <span  style="color:red">{{errMessageTo}}</span>

                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> <!-- /control-group -->



            <!--DATE PICKER-->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.account.name" >Account Name<sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select ng-model="reservation.account.id" required>
                        <option ng-repeat="p in accounts"  value="{{p.id}}" required>{{p.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> <!-- /control-group -->

            <!--<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.poc.name">POC Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select ng-model="reservation.poc.id">
                        <option ng-repeat="p in pocs" value="{{p.id}}">{{p.name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            <!--</div>--> <!-- /control-group -->
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="reservation.remark" >Remarks : <sup>*</sup></label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" required id="remarksText" class="span4" name="reservation.remark" placeholder="Enter your remarks here" ng-model="reservation.remark" />
                </div> <!-- /controls -->
            </div> <!-- /control-group -->

            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" validation-submit="editReservationForm" ng-click="updateReservation()">Save</button>
                <button ng-click="cancel()" class="btn">Cancel</button>
            </div> <!-- /form-actions -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

I have added the `required` tag along with all input fields but upon click of 'Save' button, the error messages that show 'This field is required' is not shown. The function is not getting called though.

I need help in finding the cause of this issue.

Comment: where is this text `This field is required` in html?

Comment: Where are the {{errMessageFrom}} and {{errMessageTo}} coming from? Also, where is your ng-message(s)?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

It is supposed to create a message if we use the required tag? even without span? correct?

Comment: the {{errMessageFrom}} is generating the message fine as expected. I am having issue with other fields

Comment: Try removing novalidate attribute from form tag. It will prevent the default browser validation. Any using browser validation is not a good idea. It depends on browser.

Comment: Removed the novalidate but that didnt help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `novalidate` in the `<form>` tag.

Try changing `required` to `ng-required="true"`.

`ng-required` works with `ng-model`. So make sure that ng-model exists in your input tag. (additional info)

Try adding

```
<span style="color:red" ng-show="editReservationForm.inputFieldName.$invalid && editReservationForm.inputFieldName.$touched">
                Required field.
</span>
```

where `inputFieldName` is the respective `name` attribute.

This adds for better effect although you'll need to import `angular-animate.min.js` and add it as a dependency too.